# Validate part of mail suffix

Tags: c#, regex

I'm validating mail addresses that could look something like this:

```
foo@bar.xx.com
```

but also

```
foo@bar.yy.com
```

I would like to check whether if `xx` is present or not. The first thing that came to mind was `String.Contains`, but it would obviously match any occurrences of `xx` in the string.

Is regexp the way to go? If so, please help me with the pattern.

Update: The mail can have any ending, e.g. `.com`, `.ru` etc.

Comment: What about String.EndsWith(".xx.com")? Hard to answer without knowing the exact rules which adresses to match

Comment: (edited) Super simple is to check it right after the @ sign using regex `.+@.+xx.+`

Comment: @FlatEric Yeah sorry, should have elaborated. It can have any ending.

Comment: var result=string.Split("@"), then play with result(1)

Comment: What about `String.Contains(".xx.")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to test.

It will ensure that after the `@` there is `.xx.` but may also match the string `@.xx.*`

```
.*@[^.]*[.]xx[.]
```

Or this one to ensure that there is at least one character before and after the `@`.

```
.+@[^.]+[.]xx[.]
```

Comment: Thanks. In what way does this differ from the other answer?

Comment: This pattern is also match by this string:  `@.xx.` !! and it's not correct!

Comment: The poster asked to be able to validate mail addresses containing `.xx.` after the @, ignoring the end of the address. In what way does this not meet that requirement?

Comment: @JeffreyWieder `.xx.` just a condition but i think that pattern must be valid email address.

Comment: That is not what the poster asked for. "I would like to check whether if xx is present or not." This does THAT. If the poster would like a regex that validates it is a valid email AND has `.xx.` i will update my answer to accommodate that. @filur which were you looking for?

Comment: First of all, I'm not the downvoter. To be more specific, I want to check if the mail looks like this `*@*.xx.*` where `*` is just a wildcard. Does it make sense_

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, i have updated my answer with another option if you want at least one character before and after the `@` character.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to assure that the email is valid using regex, check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) for more details.

However for your needs and a basic verification you can use the following regex:

```
^[^@]+@[^@]+\.(xx|XX).[^@^.]+$
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I make `xx` non case sentitive?

Comment: You would simple have to add a pipe symbol, so the expression will become: ^[^@]+@[^@]+\.(xx|XX).[^@^.]+$  I edited the answer also.

Comment: Or `/i` for ignore case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern: `\w+@\w+.xx.\w+`

Check Reference: http://regexr.com/

And if you want to check any email, better to seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) patterns.